# Create and added token to request in Framework 4

Tags: asp.net, frameworks, .net-4.0, identityserver4

We have created program with Framework 4 that call to ASP.NET API. We have configured identity server to add API token authoritaion.

In ASP.NET applications we have ClientCredentialsTokenRequest class, but framework 4 does not include any class to configure to do a request to identity server and get our token.

Are there any class o package to configure it?